# How to get check box state from recyclerview items on pressing Done button

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

` public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
    String game_name[];
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    //private RecyclerViewClickListener itemListener;

    card_header header;

    public CardAdapter(card_header header, String[] game_name) {
        this.game_name = game_name;
        this.header = header;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return game_name.length + 1;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_header, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolderHeader(itemView);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolderItem(itemView);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ViewHolderHeader) {
            ViewHolderHeader VHheader = (ViewHolderHeader) holder;
            VHheader.tv_heading_slot_time.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.slot_time));
        } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderItem) {
            ViewHolderItem VHitem = (ViewHolderItem) holder;
            VHitem.tv_time_slot.setText(game_name[position - 1]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public class ViewHolderHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_heading_game_name, tv_heading_1, tv_heading_2, tv_heading_3,
                tv_heading_4, tv_heading_5, tv_heading_6;

        public ViewHolderHeader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_heading_slot_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_heading_slot_time);
            tv_heading_1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_heading_1);
            tv_heading_2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_heading_2);
            tv_heading_3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_heading_3);
            tv_heading_4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_heading_4);
            tv_heading_5 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_heading_5);
            tv_heading_6 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_heading_6);

            switch (numberOfCheckBoxes){

                case 1:
                    tv_heading_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_heading_3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_heading_4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_heading_5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_heading_6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tv_heading_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_heading_4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_heading_5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_heading_6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tv_heading_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_heading_5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_heading_6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tv_heading_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_heading_6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    tv_heading_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    tv_heading_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_heading_6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolderItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TableLayout tl;
        TextView tv_time_slot;
        CheckBox cb_1, cb_2, cb_3, cb_4, cb_5, cb_6;

        public ViewHolderItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cb_1 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_1);
            cb_2 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_2);
            cb_3 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_3);
            cb_4 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_4);
            cb_5 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_5);
            cb_6 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_6);
            tv_time_slot = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time_slot);
            tl = (TableLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tl);

            switch (numberOfCheckBoxes){

                case 1:
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(1,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(2,true);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(3,true);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(4,true);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(5,true);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(6,true);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(1,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(2,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(3,true);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(4,true);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(5,true);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(6,true);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(1,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(2,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(3,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(4,true);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(5,true);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(6,true);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(1,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(2,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(3,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(4,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(5,true);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(6,true);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(1,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(2,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(3,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(4,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(5,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(6,true);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(1,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(2,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(3,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(4,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(5,false);
                    tl.setColumnCollapsed(6,false);
                    break;
            }

            cb_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    switch (getLayoutPosition()) {

                        case 1:
                            if (cb_1.isChecked()) {

                            }
                            else {

                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (cb_1.isChecked()) {

                            }
                            else {

                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (cb_1.isChecked()) {

                            }
                            else {

                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (cb_1.isChecked()) {

                            }
                            else {

                            }
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            if (cb_1.isChecked()) {

                            }
                            else {

                            }
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            if (cb_1.isChecked()) {

                            }
                            else {

                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            cb_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cb2 " + getLayoutPosition(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            cb_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cb3 " + getLayoutPosition(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            cb_4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cb4 " + getLayoutPosition(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            cb_5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cb5 " + getLayoutPosition(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            cb_6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cb6 " + getLayoutPosition(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

`I have a recyclerview which contains text item fetched from a list and few check boxes in each item. i want the state of checked check boxes when i press Done button. i want to identify each checkbox. Can someone help?

checkboxes in column has ids CB1,CB2 and so on..

**Here is the screenshot**
[image]

Comment: have you try any thing? if yes then share you code (Adapter Code)?

Comment: You might get some helpful information from these links [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972049/single-selection-in-recyclerview) and this http://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary of the above links shared by Malav Shah, have a flag representing each `CheckBox` in your model Class. These flag won't be reset when your `View`s are recycled. In your `onBindViewHolder` method, where you set your `View`'s properties, set each `CheckBox`'s value from its corresponding flag. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried using flags. but how do i get it in Done button's onclick?

Comment: In the 'Done' button's `onClick()`, you can retrieve objects contained in your Adapter. You may have to add getter method(s) to your Adapter for this. You could even use an `Array` used to init your Adapter in the beginning to retrieve items. Do you want flags from all items in your `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Then you can retrieve all objects you've put Views for in your `RecyclerView` and get the flags from them. Can you share the code where you init and set the *Adapter* for your `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 1):

The proper 'offically-endorsed' way to handle selection state on a recyclerview would be using the [**`androidx.recyclerview.selection`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/package-summary) library.

A step-by-step walkthrough on how to use the library: https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-to-recyclerview-selection-3ed9f2381504