# How to communicate between recycler view Items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler view. Each Item view holder has a media player instance. So basically recycler view displays a list of the video item.
Whenever a user starts playing an item, I want to stop any other item currently being played.

I want to know how do I get the view holder instance of the view currently playing the content so that I can stop playing it before start playing the new item.

Comment: I want to know how do i get the viewholder instance of the view currently playing the content, where is the other content? in same adapter or somewhere else ?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972049/single-selection-in-recyclerview

Comment: save the last clicked item position and code as you want

Comment: @Hemant Parmar other content is in same aadapter

Comment: @JyotiJK , Please check answer submitted by me. its doing the same.

Comment: @PardeepKumar ok than create global instance of media player, now on click of item make sure medial player is stop.

Answer (score 1):

Just user single instance of Media Player and when you start play video just check if media player is playing then stop current playing video and start the video which you want.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps

1. Take one variable naming `mCurrentPlayingPos = -1` in adapter.
2. Apply logic on click or the event when you starts playing video. Like below

   ```
   if (mCurrentPlayingPos != -1) {
       // Find view holder using this position. If view holder is not null, then use method to release 
       // player as given mCurrentPlayingPos. 
       // If viewholder is null, that is recycled to no need to do anything. 
   } else {
       // This would be very first case    
       // Set value for mCurrentPlayingPos with positionInAdapter's value 
   }
   // Setup media player and play video below
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sSelectedPos = 0;

// call this on play button click 

     for (ModelMusic data : itemList) {
     if (itemList.indexOf(data) == position) {
      sSelectedPos = position;
     data.setPlaying(true);
     } else {
      data.setPlaying(false);
     }
      notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

//POJO class to manage your play state of song.
    public class ModelMusic {
        private boolean isPlaying = false;

        public boolean isPlaying() {
            return isPlaying;
        }

        public void setPlaying(boolean playing) {
            isPlaying = playing;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No i dont think this will be good. Though it will work but its bad to refresh whole list for single item change. ( notifyDataSetChanged();)

Comment: How will you stop action of other playing items without notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: I dont know if this is the solution . but can we use  notifyItemChanged(int position) .

Comment: @tamanneupane how will you restrict user to select only one item in many number of rows. if you have not done this type of problem solving then you cant know about this approach. Without changes in setplaying instance nothing will reflect to current ui view.

Comment: Yes i do understand you but there is only  one(For first time item selected) or two(After second item select or onwards) set playing instance change. Why are you looping through entire list? And furthure notifyDataSetChanged(); is also inside for loop . That is totally wrong

Comment: Ok if you think its wrong then tell me how will u change value of first item after second item selection ? Share your answer if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two variables to store the previous click and recent click,

```
int pre=-1,recent=-1;boolean clicked=false;
```

And inside your **onClick()** method , use

```
clicked=true;
pre=recent;
recent=clickedposition;
if(pre!=-1)
this.notifyItemChanged(pre);
this.notifyItemChanged(recent);
```

And in your **onBindViewHolder()**, add this

```
 if(clicked)
 { 
    if(pre!=-1 && pos==pre)
      stop(pre);//your code to stop the video
    if(pos==recent)
      {
          playvideo(recent);
          clicked=false;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea, try to implement it;
Create a state attribute for each recyclerView item
example isPlaying, isPaused

```
public class Video {
   String url;
   boolean isPlaying;

   public void setPlaying(boolean isPlaying){
          this.isPlaying = isPlaying;
   } 

   public boolean isPlaying(){
          return isPlaying;
   }

}
```

When the video starts to play set isPlaying to true

```
public VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoViewHolder>{
     Context ctx;
     List<Video> videos;

     public VideoAdapter(Context ctx, List<Videos> videos){
           this.ctx = ctx;
           this.videos = videos;
     }

      @Override
      public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

          View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.video_view, parent, false);
          VideoViewHolder holder = new VideoViewHolder(view);
          return holder;
      }

      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(VideoViewHolder holder, int position) {
          holder.bind(videos.get(position));
          holder.setOnClickListener(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            Video videos = video.get(adapterPosition)

            if (video.isPlaying()) {
                video.setPlaying(false);
            } else {
                video.setPlaying(true);
            }

            // Notify data set change will reload all view holders and play where playing is true, and cancel where cancel is false
            notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
  }




class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
VideoView videoView;

VideoViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    videoView = (VideoView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void bind(Video video) {
    if (video.isPlaying()) {
        video.play();
    } else {
        videoView.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: How will you stop playing ,  if song is playing on 1st position and 3rd position on click of 5th row ? I have posted correct one. get a view on it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/arthur3486/ARVI
Refer this beautiful project u will get ur answer