# Manage RadioButton without RadioGroup (Click on ParentView)

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I have created one XML with 4 `CardView` contains 4 `RadioButton` and other layouts as follow:

`fragment_list_of_transport.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:id="@+id/parent_card_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_view_1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_transport_list_height"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/now_courier"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_button_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_truck_1"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_truck_1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_truck_1"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text_view_1"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/radio_button_1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title_text_view_1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_truck" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title_text_view_1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="Small express under 10 items"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_truck_1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view_1" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_round_colors"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:text="@string/button_next"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text_view_1"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/parent_card_2"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/parent_card_1">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_view_2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_transport_list_height"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/now_courier"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_button_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_truck_2"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_truck_2" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_truck_2"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text_view_2"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/radio_button_2"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title_text_view_2"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_truck" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title_text_view_2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="Small express under 10 items"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_truck_2"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view_2" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_round_colors"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:text="@string/button_next"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text_view_2"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:id="@+id/parent_card_3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/parent_card_2">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_view_3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_transport_list_height"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/now_courier"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_button_3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_truck_3"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_truck_3" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_truck_3"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text_view_3"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/radio_button_3"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title_text_view_3"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_truck" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title_text_view_3"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="Small express under 10 items"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_truck_3"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view_3" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_round_colors"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:text="@string/button_next"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text_view_3"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:id="@+id/parent_card_4"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/parent_card_3">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_view_4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_transport_list_height"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/now_courier"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_button_4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_truck_4"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_truck_4" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_truck_4"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text_view_4"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/radio_button_4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title_text_view_4"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_truck" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title_text_view_4"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="Small express under 10 items"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_truck_4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view_4" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_round_colors"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:text="@string/button_next"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text_view_4"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

Output:

[image]

I want to manage `RadioButton` on click of both `CardView` and `RadioButton` , I have used following code:

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragmentListTransport extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    FragmentListOfTransportBinding mBinding;

    public FragmentListTransport() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_list_of_transport, container, false);

        mBinding.parentCard1.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBinding.parentCard2.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBinding.parentCard3.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBinding.parentCard4.setOnClickListener(this);

        return mBinding.getRoot();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.parent_card_1:
                mBinding.radioButton1.setChecked(true);
                mBinding.radioButton2.setChecked(false);
                mBinding.radioButton3.setChecked(false);
                mBinding.radioButton4.setChecked(false);
                break;
            case R.id.parent_card_2:
                mBinding.radioButton1.setChecked(false);
                mBinding.radioButton2.setChecked(true);
                mBinding.radioButton3.setChecked(false);
                mBinding.radioButton4.setChecked(false);
                break;
            case R.id.parent_card_3:
                mBinding.radioButton1.setChecked(false);
                mBinding.radioButton2.setChecked(false);
                mBinding.radioButton3.setChecked(true);
                mBinding.radioButton4.setChecked(false);
                break;
            case R.id.parent_card_4:
                mBinding.radioButton1.setChecked(false);
                mBinding.radioButton2.setChecked(false);
                mBinding.radioButton3.setChecked(false);
                mBinding.radioButton4.setChecked(true);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any best way to manage it?

Comment: check this **[Creating Custom Radio Groups & Radio Buttons in Android](https://crosp.net/blog/software-development/mobile/android/creating-custom-radio-groups-radio-buttons-android/)**

Comment: And another way is use a `recyclerview` and **[make single selection in `recyclerview`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35060634/7666442)** it will also easy

Comment: @NileshRathod In `RecyclerView` I think it will be hard to manage as we have to notify adapter everytime when I change radio button. I have fix 4 rows only.

Comment: i don't think that check i have added link in above comment about single selection in `recyclerview`

Comment: and also if you have fixed item than create a custom radio button as per your requirement using link that i have added in my first comment i have used that and it works for me i hope it help u too

Comment: Thank you @NileshRathod But I got easiest answer which I have posted.

Comment: Yup, Even i suggest to use recyclerview. I had same requirement and i use recyclerview instead of creating separate layout for every card. And in future if you get another category you can just add in the array list all the login will remain same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't easiest way then following (If you have easy way then I will accept it.):

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragmentListTransport extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    FragmentListOfTransportBinding mBinding;

    public FragmentListTransport() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_list_of_transport, container, false);

        mBinding.parentCard1.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBinding.parentCard2.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBinding.parentCard3.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBinding.parentCard4.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBinding.radioButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBinding.radioButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBinding.radioButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBinding.radioButton4.setOnClickListener(this);

        return mBinding.getRoot();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.parent_card_1:
            case R.id.radio_button_1:
                clickedRadioButton(mBinding.radioButton1);
                break;
            case R.id.parent_card_2:
            case R.id.radio_button_2:
                clickedRadioButton(mBinding.radioButton2);
                break;
            case R.id.parent_card_3:
            case R.id.radio_button_3:
                clickedRadioButton(mBinding.radioButton3);
                break;
            case R.id.parent_card_4:
            case R.id.radio_button_4:
                clickedRadioButton(mBinding.radioButton4);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void clickedRadioButton(RadioButton radioButton) {
        mBinding.radioButton1.setChecked(false);
        mBinding.radioButton2.setChecked(false);
        mBinding.radioButton3.setChecked(false);
        mBinding.radioButton4.setChecked(false);

        radioButton.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

If anyone has easiest way then this, please post answer. I will accept.

Comment: Nice reduction of code, But using a recyclerview will be more efficient.