# Android : How to display a Sqlite Database With CheckBox in listview Automatically

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

In my Application userinput data from Diaglogbox was Stored into the Sqlite and want to Display those datas in listview along With Checkbox

Example :

[image]

I Stored Userinput in sqlite but i dont know how to Display those saved names along with Checkbox in In Listview

How to Achieve that i am new to Android !

Database :

//Display these Datas in Listview Along With CheckBox

```
 // Table 2
    private static final String TABLE2_NAME = "listitem_name";
    public static final String COLUMN1_ID = "I_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN2_TITLE = "LISTITEMS_NAME";

 onCreate(){
 String query1 =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE2_NAME + "("
                        + COLUMN1_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                        + COLUMN2_TITLE + "  TEXT ,"
                        +  COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER, " + "FOREIGN KEY("+
                        COLUMN_ID +") "
                        + "REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME +"("+COLUMN_ID +")"+ ");";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query1);
    }

     Cursor readlistAllData() {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE2_NAME;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    
            Cursor cursor = null;
            if (db != null) {
                cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            }
            return cursor;
        }
```

ActivityClass

```
 public class AddItems extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        Toolbar mToolbar;
        DatabaseHelper myDB;
        ArrayList<String> listitems;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_items);
    
            mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_button);
    
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    
                    ShowPopup();
    
                }
            });
    
            myDB = new DatabaseHelper(AddItems.this);
    
            listitems = new ArrayList<>();
    
            DisplayList();
    
        }
    
        private void DisplayList(){
    
            Cursor cursor = myDB.readlistAllData();
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
    
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
            } else {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    
                    listitems.add(cursor.getString(1));
                }
            }
        }
    
        private void ShowPopup() {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
            final EditText lname = dialog.findViewById(R.id.list_Edit_txt);
            Button add = dialog.findViewById(R.id.add);
            Button cancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    
            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Toast.makeText(AddItems.this, "add called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                    String name = lname.getText().toString();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lname.getText().toString())) {
                        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                        db.itemlist(name);
                        Toast.makeText(AddItems.this, "Added Sucessfully !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ShowPopup();
    
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(AddItems.this, "The name cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
    
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter) class you can use to make this work.
Also, you can use RecyclerView with a RecyclerView Adapter.
Using a RecyclerView:

[joshskeen.com](http://joshskeen.com) provided a step-by-step approach using a RecyclerView in http://joshskeen.com/building-a-radiogroup-recyclerview/

Below is the adapted code to fit in your scenario.

`RadioAdapter.java`

```html
public class RadioAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RadioAdapter.ViewHolder> {  
    public int mSelectedItem = -1;
    public List<String> mItems;
    private Context mContext;

    public RadioAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RadioAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.mRadio.setChecked(i == mSelectedItem);
        viewHolder.mText.setText(mItems.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public RadioButton mRadio;
        public TextView mText;

        public ViewHolder(final View inflate) {
            super(inflate);
            mText = (TextView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.text);
            mRadio = (RadioButton) inflate.findViewById(R.id.radio);
            View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mSelectedItem = getAdapterPosition();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
            itemView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            mRadio.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        }
    }
}
```

`list_view_item.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

In `AddItems.java` class

```
RadioAdapter RadioAdapter;
List<String> listItems;

@Override
protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); 
    listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    radioAdapter = new RadioAdapter(this, listItems)  
    recyclerView.setAdapter(radioAdapter);

}

private void DisplayList(){
 Cursor cursor = myDB.readlistAllData();
 if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No Data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else {
      while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
         listitems.add(cursor.getString(1));
      }
      radioAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 }
}
```

**Reference**: http://joshskeen.com/building-a-radiogroup-recyclerview/

Below are some other useful links:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview
- https://medium.com/@codeplayon/android-how-get-list-of-checked-checkboxes-from-recyclerview-android-cba31d8e3291
- [Single selection in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972049/single-selection-in-recyclerview)

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Please note the site from which this code is from has a "Copyright © 2020 joshskeen.com". I did not find an actual license.

Comment: Yes. I added the reference to the site. I hope that is okay.

Comment: I see you have a reference, but.. [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) says "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own". On the copyright issue, I'm not a lawyer, but I'm not sure one can use copyrighted material even it one links to it. If it had been copyleft or CC-BY I'm sure there would be no legal problem.

Comment: I see. How would you suggest I make changes to this answer without a legal issue?
The content of the blog actually solves the OP's issue, which is why I added the link at first.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an Android developer, so I can't direct you. I'd probably try to modify my solution by trying to do it without looking at the source. You can ping me here if you want my comments gone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221961/discussion-between-jeff-and-scratte).

Comment: @Jeff thanks For ur time and ur Ans Bro But i have Error it says " METHOD DOESNOT OVERRIDE METHODFROM ITS SUPERCLASS " https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlYVv.png

Comment: getting Error in `(RadioAdapter.java:35)` **`Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference`** on line 35 it was  `return mItems.size();`

Comment: @Kingg, I have updated my answer to fit in the activity concept you're using.

Comment: @Jeff thanks bro, the entered Data was stored into Sqlite database but it doesn’t display in listview.

Comment: Have you checked that your list has items, and you can confirm you call `radioAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding items to your list?
@Kingg