# How to draw circle on top of recycler view items upon selection

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-canvas

[image]I'm creating a application in native android application, where I have a purpose of this use case in which I have to draw a circle using canvas upon user selection  on top of   recycler View  items and also I have to able to drag the circle vertically . How can I implement that?

Comment: you have and ui link where we can se what you're trying to say?

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan- I have updated the UI. In the above image, the circle alone needs to dragged against each numbers. The number will remain always constant .

Comment: Have you try this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972049/single-selection-in-recyclerview

Comment: @Amitpandey- The link explains about the single selection in recycler view, but my requirement is completely different.  The selected circle needs to be dragged against each numbers in my case.

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan - Any updates on it??

Comment: search for recyclerview item decoration , you can definitely do it with item decorations, you can take inspiration from https://github.com/lriccardo/TimelineView,

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan - can you provide some sample for the same?

Comment: read the edit @vinayak

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan - I think the timeline implementation is different from my requirement.

Comment: Yes the implementation is different , but I don't think you are going to get some copy paste thing , you have to implement yourself the examples just give you the idea of concept , and the concept is it can be using itemdecorations